# What's the difference between the pair of functions floor()/ceil() and min()/max()?

Tags: max, min, floor, ceil

I would say all programming languages have functions with these names to choose the lesser or greater of two values:

- `min()` & `max()`
- `floor()` & `ceil()` / `ceiling()`

And some languages have both. JavaScript I believe is one example.

I've always been a bit fuzzy on the difference between the former pair and the latter pair. I have a vague impression that `min`/`max` are more simplistic and `floor`/`ceiling` are more mathematical, but that's not much to go on.

Oddly I can't find this discussed anywhere on StackOverflow or the Internet generally by searching Google. **So is there some best practices or rules of thumb to decide which of these functions to use when your programming language offers both?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is apples vs. oranges.  In most languages/APIs, `min`/`max` take two (or more) inputs, and return the smallest/biggest.  `floor`/`ceil` take one argument, and round it down or up to the nearest integer.

Comment: Oof! Seems obvious! But I won't delete it yet in case there are other blockheads out there like me who thought the same thing! `\-:`

Answer (score 15):

To my knowledge `max` and `min` are used on a collection, say an array of numbers. `Floor` and `ceiling` are used for single numbers. For example:

```
min(1, 2, 3, 4) => 1
max(1, 2, 3, 4) => 4
floor(3.5) => 3
ceiling(3.5) => 4
```

Answer (score 12):

```
min(1, 2) == 1
max(1, 2) == 2

floor(3.9) == 3
round(3.9) == 4

ceil(3.1) == 4
round(3.1) == 3

trunc, as in (int)(3.xxx) = 3 (no matter what xxx is)
```

On the definition:

`floor` is the greatest integer less than `n`.

`ceil` is the smallest integer greater than `n`.

Answer (score 8):

In Javascript:

- **Floor** Round a number downward to its nearest integer.
- **Ceil** Round a number upward to its nearest integer.
- **Round** Round a number to the nearest integer.

```js
function ceil() {
    var d = Math.ceil(5.1);

    var x = d + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("ceil").innerHTML = x; 
}

function floor() {
    var d = Math.floor(5.1);

    var x = d + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("floor").innerHTML = x; 
}

function round() {
    var d = Math.round(5.1);

    var x = d + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("round").innerHTML = x; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the different buttons to understand the concept of Ceil, Floor and Round</p>

<button onclick="ceil()">Ceil 5.1</button>
<p id="ceil"></p>

<button onclick="floor()">Floor 5.1</button>
<p id="floor"></p>

<button onclick="round()">Round 5.1</button>
<p id="round"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I realise this post is old, but an important distinction is being overlooked.

The function round() rounds towards or away from zero, while the functions ceil() and floor() round toward positive infinity and negative infinity;

This is important if dealing with both positive and negative numbers. i.e.

```
round(4.900000) = 5.000000
ceil(4.900000) = 5.000000
floor(4.900000) = 4.000000

round(4.100000) = 4.000000
ceil(4.100000) = 5.000000
floor(4.100000) = 4.000000

round(-4.100000) = -4.000000
ceil(-4.100000) = -4.000000
floor(-4.100000) = -5.000000

round(-4.900000) = -5.000000
ceil(-4.900000) = -4.000000
floor(-4.900000) = -5.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

`min()` and `max()` return the smaller or larger of 2 values, some might do more than 2 values, as in

`min(3, 5);` returns 3.

`floor()` and `ceiling()` truncate a double into an integer as in

`floor(5.3);` returns 5.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand your question, see for example:

```
a = 1.7
b = 2.8

min(a,b) = 1.7 (returns the minimum of a and b)
max(a,b) = 2.8 (returns the maximum of a and b)

floor(a) = 1 (rounds towards 0)
floor(b) = 2 (rounds towards 0)

ceil(a) = 2 (rounds up)
ceil(b) = 3 (rounds up)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please consider below for difference between Math.floor(), Math.round() and Math.ceil() in javascript:

1- `Math.floor(x)` /if x=0.99 convert to = x=0/ (Returns x rounded down to its nearest integer) 
2- `Math.ceil(x)` /if x<0.1 convert to x=1/(Returns x rounded up to its nearest integer) 
 
3-1- `Mathh.round(x)` /  if x<0.5  convert to x=0/ 
3-2- Mathh.round(x) /  if 0.5<=x<1  convert to x=1/
(Returns x rounded to its nearest integer)